# Is there a way to clear a TextBox's text without TextChanged firing?

Tags: c#, textbox, event-handling, textchanged

In my application I'd like to handle `TextBox` input in certain cases (some criteria is not filled, for example) and because `KeyDown` is useful only for keyboard input but not actual pasting from the clipboard (I wouldn't want to go through the trouble of doing that using Win32 calls anyway), I figured I'd just handle everything in my primary TextBox's `TextChanged` event. However, when there is something "wrong" and the user should not be able to type in it, if I am to call `TextBox.Clear();` on it, TextChanged fires a second time, understandably, so the message gets displayed two times, as well. That's kind of annoying. Any way I can handle TextChanged only in this case? Sample code (inside `txtMyText_TextChanged`) :

```
if (txtMyOtherText.Text == string.Empty)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The other text field should not be empty.");

    txtMyText.Clear(); // This fires the TextChanged event a second time, which I don't want.

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about to disconnect the event handler before the change and reconnect afterward?

```
if (txtMyOtherText.Text == string.Empty)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The other text field should not be empty.");
    txtMyText.TextChanged -= textMyText_TextChanged;
    txtMyText.Clear(); 
    txtMyText.TextChanged += textMyText_TextChanged;
    return;
}
```

In more complex cases it is better to have a try/finally and reenable the TextChanged event in the finally part

Comment: This never passed my mind. Thank you very much for your help. :)